# Date format gets lost

Tags: java, date, format

There have been many posts that covers this topic but however I adjust them to my code I could not find a suitable answer.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));)
{           
        String line = "";

        Person tempPerson = null;
        String dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        Date tempBirthdayDate = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {               
            String[] splitFormat = line.split("/");
            for (String s : splitFormat)
            {
                String[] datamember = s.split(", ");

                //Some more stuff...

                tempBirthdayDate = sdf.parse(datamember[3]);
                sdf.format(tempBirthdayDate);
                sdf.applyPattern(dateFormat);

                //Some more stuff...

            }

            tempPerson = new Person(...,...,...,tempBirthdayDate,...,...);
        }
}
```

Person.java copy constructor:

```
public Person(..., ..., ..., Date birthdayDate, ..., ...)
{
    this.xxx = ...;
    this.xxx = ...;
    this.xxx = ...;
    this.birthdayDate = birthdayDate;
    this.xxx = adresse;
    this.xxx = ...;
}
```

Those "..." are just place holders to shorten the code. In the source file (.txt) the date is in the same format I defined up there. But as soon as I call the toString()-Method on the birthdayDate I get following result for e.g. 05/26/1993:
Wed May 26 00:00:00 CEST 1993. Thank you for helping!

Comment: You forgot to mention what is your desired output?

Comment: The string you're looking for is returned by `sdf.format(tempBirthdayDate)`. And `sdf.applyPattern(dateFormat)` is redundant.

Comment: what else would you expect? read the doc for the methods you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the toString method of a Date object is not affected by SimpleDateFormat you initialized.

You need to create a custom class extending Date and override the toString method

```
public class CustomDate extends Date {
        ......
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(this);
        }
}
```

In Person constructor

```
public Person(..., ..., ..., CustomDate birthdayDate, ..., ...)
{
    this.xxx = ...;
    this.xxx = ...;
    this.xxx = ...;
    this.birthdayDate = birthdayDate;
    this.xxx = adresse;
    this.xxx = ...;
}
```

you can now call toString on birthdayDate and get the format you want